# How do I get the code in this Powerapps lesson on edit forms to work?

Tags: forms, connection, powerapps

I'm going through this lesson for powerapps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/add-form and when I reach the point where I put the code:

```
First(Filter(FlooringEstimates, Name=ChooseProduct.Selected.Value))
```

in the item field the code is not functioning, when I check the error it says "Invalid argument type" and there's a redline underneath "Value". I've double checked the previous steps but I'm not sure if I'm making a mistake or this lesson is outdated or what.

Comment: Did you copy and paste the line in from the tutorial? Maybe delete the text up to ChooseProduct, then add the period(.) in. Intellisense will give you some options for ChooseProduct. See if 'Selected' is one of those, then do the same for Value. I notice that the tutorial is from 2017, and it may well be that the syntax for this part has changed and you'll need .SelectedValue

Comment: Did you get a chance to verify my answer?

Comment: Come on Sully - did it work or not?

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this, the below snippet works fine. Probably a change in syntax, the expected piece after `ChooseProduct.Selected` changed to field name (ie. Name) rather than control property (ie. Value)

```
First(Filter(FlooringEstimates, Name=ChooseProduct.Selected.Name))
```

See the intellisense helping us to complete:

[image]